# Should it be Everest or the Everest?

Tags: articles

Multiple resources state that mountain peaks ("mounts") shouldn't be used with "the", e.g. Mount Fuji, however what is the situation with Everest? Youglish shows about 1000 results for "the Everest", is it grammatically wrong to say it like that?

Comment: Are the uses of "the Everest" literally referring to the mountain or are they being used metaphorically to mean "the highest peak"?

Comment: What is meant is literally mount Everest

Comment: Please post some of the results you're finding using "the Everest". The most basic research should tell you how to refer to the mountain, but it's possible to have "the Everest" in compounds, e.g. "the Everest tour".

Answer (score 2):

An article isn't used with a singular proper noun referring to a specific place, so "he plans to climb Everest" rather than "he plans to climb the Everest."

If Everest is being used as a noun modifier, then an article would be used when appropriate for the noun being modified, e.g. "the Everest summit" or "the Everest expedition."

Comment: But there are exceptions. ' ... he plans to climb the Eiger / the Matterhorn / the Jungfrau'.

Comment: Good point. Googling German descriptions of those mountains, they use definite articles ("die Jungfrau", "das Matterhorn"), so perhaps that carries over to articles being used in English for mountains with German names.

Comment: Then there's also 'the Ogre in Pakistan’s Karakoram' ([Mountaineering; UIAA](https://theuiaa.org/mountaineering/theogre/)). And the Old Man of Coniston ([ThinkAdventure.co.uk](https://www.thinkadventure.co.uk/old-man-of-coniston-circular-walk/)).